# Error: Command "yarn install" exited with 128

Tags: git, next.js, yarnpkg, vercel

https://github.com/ayaztest/wolfnft

[image]

I am having a problem uploading my Github website to vercel. I'm getting this yarn error.

Comment: Read the other parts of the error logs. There are other error messages about failed to read from a remote repo and "*Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.*"

Comment: how do it do that ?

Comment: Someone said from stack overflow that i should delete package.lock.json  i did that but nathing happened

Comment: https://wolfnft.vercel.app/  i dont know how but i can see the website i have uploaded and its working as intended

Answer (score 2):

Try This > It worked for me .. and my app is running on vercel absolutely fine. Thanks

1- yarn cache clean

2- rm yarn.lock

3- rm -rf node_modules/

and then run

4- yarn

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is the issue specifically related to yarn.lock.
A possible reason would be:

1. You installed some package accidently via npm so yarn.lock didn't
   update
2. Then you removed node_modules and installed via yarn but during that
   yarn has some conflictial changes

Solution:

- Remove yarn.lock (and package.json if accidentally you have in yarn
  project)
- Remove node_modules
- Now run yarn or yarn install

Answer (score 0):

I deleted yarn.lock and package-lock.json and then tried deploying. It worked.

Answer (score -1):

after deleting yarn i was able to upload the website to Vercel. Thank you for help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).